# When does passing an instance in place of an id work in Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Example scenario:
The model Worker `belongs_to` the model Bucket.

See the following queries:

```
1.9.3p194 :045 > Worker.where(bucket_id: Bucket.first).count
   (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "workers" WHERE "workers"."bucket_id" = 1
 => 38
1.9.3p194 :046 > Worker.where(bucket_id: Bucket.first.id).count
   (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "workers" WHERE "workers"."bucket_id" = 1
 => 38

1.9.3p194 :047 > Worker.new bucket_id: Bucket.first
 => #<Worker id: nil, email: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, bucket_id: nil>
1.9.3p194 :048 > Worker.new bucket_id: Bucket.first.id
 => #<Worker id: nil, email: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, bucket_id: 2>
```

As you can see, in case of the `where` function, passing an instance such as `Bucket.first` works in lieu of the exact `id`. So one would think it'd work for the `new` function too. Instead it fails silently!

Why does it work this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is happening in the [ActiveRecord::PredicateBuilder](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb#L49). You can see there if the value is an ActiveRecord::Base object it will call `id` on it. The `new` method does not trigger this code so it will behave differently.

I prefer to be explicit and pass in the `id` directly. However [upcoming in Rails 4](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb#L38) you will be able to do this:

```
Worker.where(bucket: Bucket.first).count
```

That nicely parallels with initialization:

```
Worker.new(bucket: Bucket.first)
```

In general, I recommend passing an `id` if the attribute you are setting/matching ends in `_id`.

**Update:** I also wanted to point out, the initialization will inherit the `where` conditions. So this will work in Rails 3.2:

```
Worker.where(bucket_id: Bucket.first).new
```

I'm assuming that ends up going through the PredicateBuilder, but not certain about that. Even though this works I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, `Bucket.first` will return an instant object, but `Bucket.first.id` will only return id of the instant object.

So, when you creating `Worker.new` and pass `bucket_id: Bucket.first`, it will actually do not work, on the other hand,

```
Worker.new bucket_id: Bucket.first.id
```

it will pass the correct param in order to create new Worker.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `.new` you are creating a blank record but it has no ID yet.  With Active Record this is frequently used for forms.

This is different from say `.create` which, if given the required valid parameters will create a record with an ID.  Similarly, selecting a record with `Bucket.first` gets an existing record that has an ID.

If you use `.new`, set the required parameters and then do a `.save` you will then get an ID.

Comment: Not at all what he was asking